# Get parameter from another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, and i'm not a php developer and not very eager to start either so I'm avoiding it like the plague, but I do have a requirement that requires a little bit of extra coding. I need to:

1. go to a different website,
2. download that page,
3. check for a certain phrase,
4. if phrase exists, extract a link from that page
5. and if link is returned I need to show that link on my wordpress site.

Currently, I have an asp.net page that does this and i'm hosting that page in an iframe on my wordpress site. but i'd like to do it without an iframe.

Question is, is there anyway for javascript to go to a different page (my asp.net page) and get a parameter (link) from it. If link is provided i will show certain content on wordpress site.

Or can javascript download a text file from the server? problem with that is i need a trigger to update the text file.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should understand is that by "avoiding [PHP] like the plague" you're inadvertently avoiding the proper way of doing things. Javascript is a client-side language, and PHP is a server-side language. By asserting that you only want the load on the client's end (the kind of logic involved in what you want to do isn't exactly lightweight), you can potentially end up with a VERY slow webpage.

Not to mention, this type of situation is analogous to using a hammer to do a backhoe's job.

Either way, to answer your question, yes. You can use the jQuery [Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method in tandem with Javascript's [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7df7sf4x(v=vs.94).aspx) method.

What you should TRY to do, however, is make a [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request using PHP, and then cache the page on your server. By doing this, you will limit the number of calls to a given page, and optimize load times.

Please consider the second option, even as an attempt in good practice. Good luck.

Comment: I had a feeling the first suggestion would be to try and use php. I understand the difference between server and client, that's why currently I do this in asp.net. I'll give it a shot, web technologies evolve way too fast and if I don't need it, I hate to waste the time learning about it. I only do asp.net because its .net...

Comment: I figured you knew, but sometimes illustrating a point requires the reiteration of some already understood concepts. Either way, I hope everything works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax and connect to a different page (on your server) which is written in server-sided language (like asp.net, as you said), that connects to the remote website.

[More about Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Comment: ah, ajax, the other plague. I guess I better start reading, from quick scanning it looks like it could do what I'm after.